# Can I use Indian electronic appliance in US

Tags: usa, electronic-items, power

I plan to take my desktop with me to America. I have read around the web that following power specification is necessary for appliances to operate in US
Voltage: 110V & Frequency: 60Hz.

My monitor's specification says 100-240V, 50-60Hz, so that should be working fine. But my Cabinet's PSU (Cooler master Thunder 450) says only 230Vac (47-63Hz). Will that work fine in US, or should I get a new PSU?

Comment: [It won't work](http://www.coolermaster.com/product/Detail_aj01/powersupply/P1302180516680d/Specs.html). But you can replace it in the US for less than $50 with a similar PSU that will work on both 110 and 230 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PSU doesn't say it will work on the lower voltage then it probablly won't.

Normal sockets in the US are 120V. Most US houses will have both 120V and 240V available at the breaker panel in a "split phase" arrangement but normally the only 240V sockets will be specific ones for high power appliances (stoves, clothes driers, etc). If you own the property it would be possible to install a 240V outlet specifically for your PSU but it's almost certainly easier and cheaper to just buy a new PSU.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what this has got to do with travel... You will need a new PSU unless your PSU also operates at 110V. Your alternative would be to use it with a high power transformer. I would not recommend it.